# Drop Down Title Change When Item Selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code below for 2 ddls containing 3 items. Is it possible to have the title shown on each drop down list change to whatever item the user selects, but only using vanilla JavaScript or CSS? Anything would help, cheers.

```css
 .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 13px;
        font-size: 16px;
        width:125px;
        height:45px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am unclear on your question. What title do you want to change?

Comment: Like one ddl says Location, so if I click Link 1,2 or 3 under location it changes the text from location to the item I selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');

  for(var  i =0;i<div.length;i++){

  for(var  j =0;j<div[i].children.length;j++){

   div[i].children[j].addEventListener('click',function(){

     this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
   })
  }
  }
```

```css
.dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 13px;
        font-size: 16px;
        width:125px;
        height:45px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Vanilla JS.

You'll simply attach click listeners to each anchor, then traverse up the parent nodes to find the button and replace the innerHTML.

Please note that `anchors` is all the links in you page, so if there are other anchors on your page beside what you've provided, you'll need to be a little more specific when defining the anchors array.

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
  var thisAnchor = anchors[i];
    thisAnchor.onclick = function () {
        var btn = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        btn.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 13px;
        font-size: 16px;
        width:125px;
        height:45px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle for you.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vny5f2fm/1/%20JSFIDDLE)

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button id="btn1" class="dropbtn">Location</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSelect('Link 1','btn1')">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="doSelect('Link 2','btn1')">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="doSelect('Link 3','btn1')">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="btn2" class="dropbtn">Category</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSelect('Link 1','btn2')">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#"  onclick="doSelect('Link 2','btn2')">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#"  onclick="doSelect('Link 3','btn2')">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function doSelect(text,btn){

    var myElement = document.getElementById(btn);

myElement.innerText = text;

}
</script>
```