# Replace the heading name with dropdown name when clicked

Tags: javascript, css

Here I have a dropdown button where it has following three list in dropdown. When I click the list in the dropdown it has to replace the name with the list name in the dropdown. Help me out with the issue. Thanks in advance. Heres the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/e8bny3kv/

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems you just copied the example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h) and did no research whatsoever

Comment: Yes! I'm searching for the result meanwhile I posted in stack overflow too

Comment: you want to change the `<h2>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614879/drop-down-title-change-when-item-selected

Comment: Add this code  $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
$("button").text($(this).text());

})   Even i will suggest to use <select><option></option></select> For reference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
`$('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).html());
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.dropdown>button').addEventListener('click',function(e){
e.currentTarget.innerText = 'focused';
});
```

Comment: Can you make changes in fiddle if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 
[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c23ufqgw/)

```
$('.dropdown-item').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').html(($(this).text()))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using simple Javascript -

Try this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z1qbfgcp/1/

```
let dropDownItem = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')
   dropDownItem.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.closest('.dropdown').children[0].innerText = this.innerText
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
$("button").text($(this).text());

})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: U excepting this type

Comment: Thats what I posted in the above link. And yes that is what I'm expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this, just delete the "Dropdown button" text and use the ::before pseudo-element to make the text change in the different states.

```
.dropdown.show .dropdown-toggle::before{
  content:'Dropdown button: open'
}
.dropdown-toggle::before{
  content:'Dropdown button: close'
}
```